# whats the difference between git push heroku vs git push heroku master?

Tags: git, heroku, push

i've always thought both were interchangeable and have been doing git push heroku as shortcut. Is there a difference between the two?

Comment: It does exactly what it says in `git help push`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git push heroku master` pushes the master branch to the `heroku` remote.

`git push heroku` pushes the *default* branch (which is usually master) to the `heroku` remote.